# What module can I use to parse RSS feeds in a Perl CGI script?

Tags: perl, rss, cgi, feedparser

I am trying to find a RSS parser that can be used with a Perl CGI script. I found `simplepie` and that's really easy parser to use in PHP scripting. Unfortunately that doesn't work with a Perl CGI script. Please let me know if there is anything that's easy to use like `simplepie`.

I came across this one [RssDisplay](http://www.decafbad.com/twiki/bin/view/Main/RssDisplay#Documentation) but I am not sure about the usage and also how good it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org): [XML::RSS::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::RSS::Parser).

> [XML::RSS::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::RSS::Parser) is a lightweight liberal parser of RSS feeds. This parser is "liberal" in that it does not demand compliance of a specific RSS version and will attempt to gracefully handle tags it does not expect or understand. The parser's only requirements is that the file is well-formed XML and remotely resembles RSS.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use XML::RSS::Parser;
use FileHandle;

my $parser = XML::RSS::Parser->new;

unless ( -e 'uploads.rdf' ) {
    require LWP::Simple;
    LWP::Simple::getstore(
        'http://search.cpan.org/uploads.rdf',
        'uploads.rdf',
    );
}
my $fh = FileHandle->new('uploads.rdf');
my $feed = $parser->parse_file($fh);

print $feed->query('/channel/title')->text_content, "\n";

my $count = $feed->item_count;
print "# of Items: $count\n";

foreach my $i ( $feed->query('//item') ) {
    print $i->query('title')->text_content, "\n";
}
```

Comment: "remotely resembles RSS" - undoubtedly one of the best technical specs I've read in several months...

Comment: **@DVK:** You realize that's a copy/paste from CPAN?  As with my answer -- straight copy/paste.  And, to give credit, the block of code is not from that CPAN link.

Answer (score 1):

### Available Perl Modules

---

- #### [XML::RSS::Tools](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::RSS::Tools)
- #### [XML::RSS::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::RSS::Parser):

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -w
  use strict;

  use XML::RSS::Parser;
  use FileHandle;

  my $p = XML::RSS::Parser->new;
  my $fh = FileHandle->new('/path/to/some/rss/file');
  my $feed = $p->parse_file($fh);

  # output some values 
  my $feed_title = $feed->query('/channel/title');
  print $feed_title->text_content;
  my $count = $feed->item_count;
  print " ($count)\n";
  foreach my $i ( $feed->query('//item') ) { 
     my $node = $i->query('title');
     print '  '.$node->text_content;
     print "\n"; 
  }
  ```
- #### [XML::RSS::Parser::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::RSS::Parser::Lite) (Pure Perl):

  ```
  use XML::RSS::Parser::Lite;
  use LWP::Simple;

  my $xml = get("http://url.to.rss");
  my $rp = new XML::RSS::Parser::Lite;
  $rp->parse($xml);

  print join(' ', $rp->get('title'), $rp->get('url'), $rp->get('description')), "\n";

  for (my $i = 0; $i < $rp->count(); $i++) {
     my $it = $rp->get($i);
     print join(' ', $it->get('title'), $it->get('url'), $it->get('description')), "\n";
  }
  ```
- #### [dirtyRSS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/dirtyRSS):

  ```
  use dirtyRSS;

  $tree = parse($in);
  die("$tree\n") unless (ref $tree);
  disptree($tree, 0);
  ```

Comment: see Sinan's answer for another example of XML::RSS::Parser - the module I recommend

Comment: hi, thanks. I tired installing the xml::rss module after reading this here http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5487340.html# but the module did not install properly. I am waiting for the hosting company tech support to look at this. I will look into what you have mentioned and try out.